# barcode settings not as i want

Tags: python, keyboard, barcode-scanner

i tried to wrote a code that only respond to my barcode scanner. even when i do other things on the computer. this code work but the problem i have is that i have 2 keyboards. 1 is the barcodescanner and the other my normal keyboard. it responds on the scanner perfectly but still it responds to my normal keyboard aswell. i not want this. and the other problem i have is. if i'm in my notepad for example and if i scan, the code work, but the string with a enter on the end apear in the notepad aswell. i not want this too.
is there someone who can help me?

```
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
import os
import keyboard

# Define the barcode scanner input string
barcode_input = ""

# Define the barcode scanner key prefix
barcode_prefix = "Barcode: "

# list of collected data
info = []

def is_file_exists(file_path):
    try:
        workbook = load_workbook(file_path)
        workbook.close()
        return True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return False

def scan(barcode):

    for i in range(20):
        info.append('')

    def save_button_pressed():
        if info:
            workbook = load_workbook("data.xlsx") if is_file_exists("data.xlsx") else Workbook()
            sheet = workbook.active
            sheet.append(info)
            workbook.save("data.xlsx")
            workbook.close()
            print("Data saved to data.xlsx")
        else:
            print("No checkboxes selected.")
        window.destroy()

    def checkbox_pressed(checkbox_id):
        checkbox_state = checkbox_vars[checkbox_id].get()
        if checkbox_state:
            # Checkbox is checked
            current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            print(f"task {checkbox_id + 1} is checked! time: {current_time}")
            info[checkbox_id + 3] = current_time
        else:
            # Checkbox is unchecked
            print(f"Checkbox {checkbox_id + 1} is unchecked!")
            info[checkbox_id + 3] = ''

    info[0] = barcode
    info[1] = os.getlogin()
    info[2] = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    # Create the main window
    window = tk.Tk()

    # Set window attributes to make it appear as a popup
    window.lift()
    window.attributes('-topmost', True)
    window.after_idle(window.attributes, '-topmost', False)

    # Create checkbox variables and checkboxes
    checkbox_vars = []
    checkboxes = []
    for i in range(12):
        checkbox_var = tk.BooleanVar()
        checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(window, text=f"taak {i + 1}", variable=checkbox_var, command=lambda i=i: checkbox_pressed(i))
        checkbox.pack()
        checkbox_vars.append(checkbox_var)
        checkboxes.append(checkbox)

    # Create the "save" button
    save_button = tk.Button(window, text="save", command=save_button_pressed)
    save_button.pack()

    # Start the main loop
    window.mainloop()


# Define the function to handle keyboard events
def handle_key_event(e):
    global barcode_input
    global info

    # Check if the event is from the barcode scanner
    if e.name == "enter":
        # Process the barcode input
        barcode = barcode_input.replace(barcode_prefix, "")
        scan(barcode)
        print(info)
        info = []
        # Reset the barcode input
        barcode_input = ""
    else:
        # Append the event key to the barcode input
        barcode_input += e.name

# Start listening to keyboard events
keyboard.on_press(handle_key_event)

# Keep the script running until interrupted
keyboard.wait('esc')
```

1. when i use my normal keyboard i want it not to activate the code
2. when i'm in notepad for example and i scan. the string not apear there. only i want it register in the code.